# Get source information from dynamic "image"

Tags: php, email

I am currently developing a newsletter marketing system, to which I want to include certain statistics. I'm currently capable of keeping track of the amount of views a certain mailing has gotten by including a php file as an image that updates the database.

`<img src="http://siteroot/counter.php" />`

Now I am wondering if it is possible to retrieve any information such as OS or browser (probably not) and if not, if it is possible to retrieve the url on which the e-mail was read.

I want to know this so I can see what kind of e-mail client was used to read the e-mail and things like that.

Comment: try the referral in apache log

Comment: Is it possible to read these logs from PHP? The idea is that these statistics get shot into a database, and it will be way too much to process them manually.

Comment: apache log normally is pipe into a file in the web-server that hosting the apache, so, you need to have the access to that server, then you can do whatever you know ... or simply apache log analyzer like awstat - http://awstats.sourceforge.net

Comment: Apache logs reading is something I will definitely look into, but might be too much work / trouble finding out how. Thanks for the suggestion at least :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in your script, which generally contains the browser and OS version information, and occasionally what toolbars/extensions/plugins are installed. It's not 100% reliable, as the information is under user control.

Comment: Oh, I actually tried `$_SERVER` but nothing came out, now when I look again it does work. I guess I did something else wrong, will use this.